# Value Error when adding adding a layer in ArcGIS Pro arcpy script

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, valueerror, addlayer

In a script, I'm creating a feature layer and trying to add it to a map in ArcGIS Pro 2.3.0. When I try to add it though, I get a ValueError. Any ideas why and how to fix it? m is the map object. The layer is created.

FWIW, I'm running the script in Spyder, Python 3.6.6, which I installed (maybe correctly, maybe not) in the default ArcGIS Pro environment. It seems to recognize the arcpy module, although there's no intellisense.

```
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject(prj)
m = aprx.listMaps()[0]
target = m.listLayers('Cities Villages Twps')[0]
try:    
    target.definitionQuery = "NAME = 'Chicago'"
    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(target, 'GPP')
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management('GPP', "Area501")
    print(type("Area501"))   # str
    print(type(Area501))     # NameError: name 'Area501' is not defined
    print(type(Area501[0]))  # NameError: name 'Area501' is not defined
    m.addLayer(Area501[0])   # NameError: name 'Area501' is not defined   

except Exception:
    print(arcpy.GetMessages())
    print('\n')
    tb.print_exc(limit=1, file=sys.stdout)

del aprx
```

Comment: 1 - Please don't just say "I get a `ValueError`", when you get an error, *always* include the *entire* exception traceback as text (formatted as code `{}`) in your question.  2 - Never ever use `try: except:` statements when posting questions here, you won't be able to see the *entire* exception traceback.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's failing because you're passing in a string to the `addLayer` function and hoping the method will resolve to the layer you created. In short, it wont. You'll need to be more explicit in what you pass `addLayer` - the actual layer from the result. In the below code I know that grabbing the first index (`[0]`) gets the layer object.

```
fooResult = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management('Points', "fooName")
type("fooName")
# <class 'str'>
type(fooResult )
# <class 'arcpy.arcobjects.arcobjects.Result'>
type(fooResult [0])
# <class 'arcpy._mp.Layer'>

p = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("current")
m = p.listMaps()[0]
m.addLayer("fooName")
# value error  - its a string
m.addLayer(fooResult)
# value error  - its a result object
m.addLayer(fooResult[0])
# [<arcpy._mp.Layer object at 0x000002D941E296D8>]
```

Comment: Thanks, but when I leave off the quotes I get 'NameError: name 'Area501' is not defined'. Added some more code in case the problem is there.

Comment: You need to assign a variable to `arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management('GPP', "Area501")`, the very first line of code -- I used the variable foo and the string foo (bad form on my part). I just updated to make it a bit more clear in the differences.

Comment: That worked, thanks!